# Golang, cors and angularjs - header missing

Tags: angularjs, go, cors

I'm using [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors) in my Go API to allow my Angularjs app to make direct requests. I've added the following code to configure CORS:

```
crs := cors.New(cors.Options{AllowCredentials: true})
n.Use(crs) //Negroni include
```

but I'm getting the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** message in the browser when I make a request.

My request looks like this:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: endPoint + version + method,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(':' + appId)
    },
    data: params
}

$http(req).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(null, data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(data);
    });
```

How can I get round this?

Comment: My guess would be your webserver isn't responding to OPTIONS requests, but i'm not familiar enough to golang to be sure or suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it! I noticed that a few different headers were being sent with the request and I had to explicitly allow all of them.

```
AllowedHeaders: []string{"accept", "authorization", "content-type"}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You can also use a wildcard for all types: `AllowedHeaders:   []string{"*"}`